# Android Studio Dex writing phase: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream

Tags: android-studio

I get the following error when building the project from Android Studio 2.2.3

```
ERROR: Dex writing phase: file '/home/calin/SomeAndroidApp/build/intermediates/incremental/transformJackWithJackForGoogleDevDebug/08/F8B275A091345CBD539842873B9FAEC14C0289' failed to be read: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
```

Android Studio is configured to use gradle wrapper

I can run gradle tasks from the command line using the wrapper with no issues, the dex phase works fine in terminal.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was using compile option with java 1_8 and jack, switched to using retro_lambda and all seems to work fine again.

Apparently there is a known issue with jack that will pe addressed in gradle plugin 2.4